# How to randomly chose an array and then randomly chose an element within in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm displaying images through arrays. My issue is with the function `changeOfferRandom` what I'm hoping to do here is delete the current image from it's random array so it doesn't appear again then display another image from a random array.

I'm new to this so I wasn't sure at all how to attempt this. The reason I don't have all these images in a single array is because I'm adding a function later to only display images based on tags. The arrays are based on tags. With deletion anyway I believe I need to be able to recognise what image is being displayed.

```
var data = [];

function importJson(str) {

    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {


        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){


        data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response);
        alert(xmlhttp.response);
        var fullindex = data.clothes.length + data.food.length + data.sport.length;



        for (var sport_index = 0; sport_index < data.sport.length; sport_index++) {

                var id1 = data.sport[sport_index].ImagesId;
                var url1 = data.sport[sport_index].ImagesPath;
                var tag1 = data.sport[sport_index].Tag;

          }


            for (var food_index = 0; food_index < data.food.length; food_index++) {
                var id2 = data.food[food_index].ImagesId;
                var url2 = data.food[food_index].ImagesPath;
                var tag2 = data.food[food_index].Tag;

            }

            for (var clothes_index = 0; clothes_index < data.clothes.length; clothes_index++) {
                var id3 = data.clothes[clothes_index].ImagesId;
                var url3 = data.clothes[clothes_index].ImagesPath;
                var tag3 = data.clothes[clothes_index].Tag;

            }

            function firstRandom(){
                var possibleImages = [url3, url2, url1];
                var offer = possibleImages[(Math.random() * possibleImages.length)|0];
                buildImage(offer);

            }

            firstRandom();
        }

    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://server/~name/folder/many.php");
    xmlhttp.responseType = "json";
    xmlhttp.send();


    function buildImage(imagesrc) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = imagesrc;
        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);



    }


}


function changeOfferRandom() {
         delete data[currentImage]; //not sure how to achieve this.
         var allArrays = [url3, url2, url1]; //not sure how to access the full arrays.
         var randomO = allArrays[(Math.random() * possibleImages.length)|0];
         buildImage(randomO);
}


window.onload = importJson();
```

xmlhttp.response looks like this:

```
{"sport":[
  {"ImagesId":"34","ImagesPath":"http:\/\/server\/~name\/folder\/images\/24-08-2014-1408868419.png","Tag":"sport"},
  {"ImagesId":"30","ImagesPath":"http:\/\/server\/~name\/folder\/images\/23-08-2014-1408824125.png","Tag":"sport"}],
"clothes":[
  {"ImagesId":"33","ImagesPath":"http:\/\/server\/~name\/folder\/images\/23-08-2014-1408824179.png","Tag":"clothes"},
  {"ImagesId":"32","ImagesPath":"http:\/\/server\/~name\/folder\/images\/23-08-2014-1408824166.png","Tag":"clothes"}],
"food":[
  {"ImagesId":"31","ImagesPath":"http:\/\/server\/~name\/folder\/images\/23-08-2014-1408824158.png","Tag":"food"}]
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about what your actual problem is? Does your code not work, and if yes, what is the error, the intended vs. actual behaviour etc?

Comment: Code works in terms of creating the first random image. I need now to create now a function explained at the bottom of my code called changeOfferRandom. I need to delete the current offer and display a new random offer. This is my problem. The images are loading into arrays and creating the first random image is working.

Comment: Could you post a simple example for what `http://server/~name/folder/many.php` might send back?

Comment: I edited to add that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your three `for`-loops make no sense, they should be removed. You are reassigning the same three variables multiple times.

Secondly, I'd store the object of the currently shown image (the one that has `imagePath`) in a global variable, so you can access it later.
To remove the currently shown image in `changeOfferRandom` you can then say

```
var tagArray = data[currentlyShownOffer.Tag];
tagArray.splice(tagArray.indexOf(currentlyShownOffer), 1);
```

which, in constrast to `delete`, does not leave an empty slot.

To get a new random offer, go with

```
var tags = Object.keys(data);
var randomTag = tags[Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.length)];
window.currentlyShownOffer = randomTag[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomTag.length)];
```

This way, your original tagified arrays are preserved, and can be accessed later.

Comment: Do I still use my buildImage function to display the images in the div content? Thank you for this and would the second piece of code go within a function?

Comment: Plus are my for loops resigning to the same? url1 url2 url3 are different

Comment: yes, the second piece is a function, that is called whenever you exchange the picture. Note that I did not include code to actually exchange the source of the ```img```. Your for-loops are not needed at all, as they only touch the data and assign it to a few variables. You don't need those variables.

Comment: I'm just beginning out this area of programming. I'm struggling to understand. What would i need to do to display the image.

Comment: Any help on how to get my ideal end product up and running would be greatly appreciated. I was a random image firstly and then a function to select another random image. Then I would like have a function to select a random image from all the tags minus a specific one or two and finally never have an image repeat.

Comment: I threw some bits together, but I won't develop your whole thing for you: http://jsbin.com/fasabi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the index and which array in order to remove the item from said array with [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp):

```
array.splice(indexOfCurrentImage, 1); // deletes 1 item starting from indexOfCurrentImage
```

You can combine arrays with [concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp):

```
var allArrays = data.sport.concat(data.food, data.clothes);
```

So I would `concat()` everything to 1 array and store the index of the image currently on display in some variable that you can later use to `splice()`

Comment: In the question it is said that the arrays have to be kept separate, not joined, for later tag-specific access.

Comment: A downvote because of that? really? I'm not deleting the original arrays by concatting them.